# How to deal with Slices as inputs and outputs in Go ASM

Tags: go, assembly, plan-9

I am trying to understand how to send more complicated values to and from Go ASM functions; beyond the typical uint in, uint out case.  I stumbled upon a great example of this advanced usage in the `crypto/elliptic` with the function  [p256BigToLittle](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/elliptic/p256_asm_arm64.s#L72) in `p256_asm_arm64.s`. It takes an byte slice and uint64 slice, it then processes the bytes and puts the output value into the uint64 slice. Below is the function with the preprocessor define statements substituted.  Here are the main things I do not understand:

- I cannot find define statements for `res` or `in` so are these being resolved at compile time from the function signature in the .go file? (IE: if I made a function `func myFunc(arg1 *int)` can I reference `arg1` in the corresponding asm file?)
- Where did the magic number `+24` in  `MOVD    in+24(FP), R1` come from?
- I am assuming the `1*16(R1)` is just meant to point to the second element of the in byte slice (8*2)? How do you know the spacing between elements of a slice? If `in` were a uint32 slice would the second element be be `1*64(R1)`?
- Where is the Go Slice header during all of this? How is it being avoided?

```
// func p256BigToLittle(res []uint64, in []byte)
TEXT ·p256BigToLittle(SB),NOSPLIT,$0
    MOVD    res+0(FP), R0
    MOVD    in+24(FP), R1

    LDP 0*16(R1), (R3, R4)
    LDP 1*16(R1), (R5, R6)

    REV R3, R3
    REV R4, R4
    REV R5, R5
    REV R6, R6

    STP (R6, R5), 0*16(R0)
    STP (R4, R3), 1*16(R0)
    RET
```

Comment: `res` and `in` are just mnemonic.  `go vet` checks if the offsets match, but apart from that, they have no function.  You have to manually give the correct offset.  Read https://golang.org/doc/asm for details.

Comment: @fuz thanks again for the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @fuz think you can explain that `+24` though? How is that determined to be the beginning on the input array?

Comment: A slice header is three words of data (24 byte).  The base pointer of the second slice argument is thus the third word of arguments on the stack.  The zeroth word is the base pointer of the first slice header.